# Implementing Concurrency in udp servers

Tags: c, udp

Is there any easy way to implement concurrency in udp servers. In TCP we have a connection which can be used to distinguish clients which is not the case in UDP. So is there any other way in which a client can be uniquely identified from another which is trying to connect to the server so that the server can fork a process for each new datagram which is from a new client. Or is there any alternative implementation without using forks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a list of already "connected" clients, and when a new datagram is received then check against this list.

Comment: is there also a way to find whn one of the client ends the connection with server ?

Comment: @AccessDenied As UDP is unconnected, not really. You have to modify the protocol to include a "goodbye" message and/or an "I'm alive" request-response message to keep track of which clients are still "connected".

Answer (score 1):

You will need to look at the sockaddr struct that you pass a pointer of to recvfrom after recvfrom returns. That will tell you where the data's coming from.

Comment: is there also a way to find whn one of the client ends the connection with server ?

Comment: @AccessDenied As Joachim said above, UDP is **unconnected**. This means it *has* *no* *connections*. Thus, a client cannot end the connection.